# Wordpress doesn't show all posts in database

Tags: database

I have around 140 post in database but wordpress admin page shows just 50 post. How could I let wordpress shows all the posts in database?

Thanks

Comment: 3x the posts in the DB could mean that you also got trashed posts, attachments, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure those aren't pages, drafts, trashed, revisions or attachments? To make sure that those aren't such, run the following in

- phpMyAdmin (Query tab - field "SQL query on database [database name]:")
- Adminer
- In the terminal
- …

and see how many results you get:

```
select * from wp_posts where post_status='publish'
```

Comment: Thanks Alex you are right. How could I manage those hidden posts?

Comment: You can install Wp Optimize, a plugin that deletes everything you don't need anymore and optimizes your database.

Answer (score 0):

The post row in database is much more broad than what post is in admin interface. Extra posts are not something hidden, there are merely instances of things that aren't of `post` post type and are not displayed as such (or at all in some cases).

You don't really need to manage those, WP does that nicely on its own. The one exclusion would probably be [post revisions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Post_Revisions).